# How to run IntellijIDEA (Spark and Scala) code in Apache Spark in terminal mode

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, terminal, apache-spark

I have written my code in IntelliJIDEA (Scala and Spark) and i want to run this code on linux using terminal how can i do this? I can't access to Graphical mode in this Linux Server.

for example this is a code similar my code:

```
package LDAv1

import java.io._

import org.apache.commons.math3.special._
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._


object SparkLDA {

    implicit def arrayToVector(s: Array[Int]) = new Vector(s)
    implicit def vectorToArray(s: Vector) = s.data

    def main(args: Array[String]){

        var numTopics:Int=3
      var inPath:String="data/MR.dat"
      var outPath:String="data"
      var master:String="local[*]"
      var iter:Int=100
        var mem="4g"
      var debug=false

      lda(inPath,outPath,master,numTopics,(50/numTopics),0.1,iter,debug,mem);
    }

    def lda(pathToFileIn:String,pathToFileOut:String,URL:String,numTopics:Int,alpha:Double,beta:Double,numIter:Int,deBug:Boolean,mem:String){
        val (conf,sc)=initializeSpark(URL,deBug,mem)
        var(documents,dictionary,topicCount)=importText(pathToFileIn,numTopics,sc)
        val ll:MutableList[Double]= MutableList[Double]()
        for(i<-0 to numIter){
            var (doc,dict,tC)=step(sc,documents,numTopics,dictionary,topicCount,alpha,beta)
            documents=doc
            dictionary=dict
            topicCount=tC
            if(deBug)ll+=logLikelihood(dictionary,topicCount,alpha,beta)
            System.gc()
        }
        saveAll(documents,ll,sc,dictionary,topicCount,pathToFileOut,deBug)
    }


    def initializeSpark(URL:String,debug:Boolean,mem:String)={
        if(!debug)Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
        val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Spark LDA")
        .setMaster(URL)
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        (conf,sc)
    }

    def importText(pathToFileIn:String,numTopics:Int,sc:SparkContext)={
        val stopWords =sc.broadcast(List[String]("a","able","about","above","according","accordingly","across","actually","after"));
        val textFile=sc.textFile(pathToFileIn,4)
        val documents=textFile.map(line=>{
            val topicDistrib=new Array[Int](numTopics)
            val lineCleaned=line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]","").toLowerCase()
            (lineCleaned.split(" ").map(word=>{
                var topic:Int=0
            var wrd:String=""
            if(word.length()>1&&(!stopWords.value.contains(word))){
                topic =Integer.parseInt(Math.round(Math.random()*(numTopics-1)).toString)
                topicDistrib.increment(topic)
                wrd=word
            }
            (wrd,topic)
            })
            ,topicDistrib)
        })
        val(dictionary,topicCount)=updateVariables(documents,numTopics)
        (documents,dictionary,topicCount)
    }

    def updateVariables(documents:RDD[(Array[(String, Int)], Array[Int])],numTopics:Int)={
        val dictionary=documents.flatMap(line=>line._1).map(tuple=>{
            var value:Array[Int]=new Array[Int](numTopics)
        if(!tuple._1.equals("")){
            value(tuple._2)+=1
        }
        (tuple._1,value)
        }).reduceByKey((a:Array[Int],b)=>{
            for(i<-0 to a.length-1){
                a(i)+=b(i)
            }
            (a)
        }).collect().toMap
        println(dictionary.take(2))
        val topicCount:Array[Int]=new Array[Int](numTopics)
        dictionary.foreach(t=>topicCount.add(t._2))
        (dictionary,topicCount)
    }

    def step(sc:SparkContext,documents:RDD[(Array[(String, Int)], Array[Int])],numTopics:Int,dict:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Array[Int]],tC: Array[Int],alpha:Double,beta:Double)={
        val dictionary=sc.broadcast(dict)
        val topicCount=sc.broadcast(tC)
        val v=dict.size
        val doc=documents.map(tuple=>{
            val topicDistrib=tuple._2
                    val line=tuple._1
            val lineupDated=line.map(t=>{
                val word=t._1
                var top=t._2
                if(!t._1.equals("")){
                    topicDistrib.decrement(top)
                    top=gibbsSampling(topicDistrib,dictionary.value(word),topicCount.value,alpha,beta,v)
                    topicDistrib.increment(top)
                }
                (word,top)
            })
            (lineupDated,topicDistrib)
        })
        val(dicti,topC)=updateVariables(doc,numTopics)
        (doc:RDD[(Array[(String, Int)], Array[Int])],dicti,topC)
    }

    def saveAll(documents: RDD[(Array[(String, Int)], Array[Int])],LogLikelihood:MutableList[Double],sc: SparkContext, dictionary: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Array[Int]], topicCount: Array[Int],path: String,deBug:Boolean){
        removeAll(path)
        saveDocuments(documents,path)
        saveDictionary(sc,dictionary,path)
        saveTopicCount(sc,topicCount,path)
        if(deBug)saveLogLikelihood (sc,LogLikelihood, path)
    }

    def saveDocuments (documents: RDD[(Array[(String, Int)], Array[Int])], path: String) {
        removeAll(path+"/documentsTopics")
        documents.map {
        case (topicAssign, topicDist) =>
        var topicDistNorm:Array[Double] = topicDist.normalize()
        val probabilities = topicDistNorm.toList.mkString(", ") 
                (probabilities)
        }.saveAsTextFile(path+"/documentsTopics")
    }

    def saveDictionary(sc: SparkContext, dictionary: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Array[Int]], path: String) {
        removeAll(path+"/wordsTopics")
        val dictionaryArray = dictionary.toArray
                val temp = sc.parallelize(dictionaryArray).map {
                case (word, topics) =>
                var topicsNorm:Array[Double] = topics.normalize()
                val topArray = topicsNorm.toList.mkString(", ") 
                        val wordCount = topics.sumAll()
                        val temp2 = List(word, wordCount, topArray).mkString("\t")
                        (temp2)
        }
        temp.saveAsTextFile(path+"/wordsTopics")
    }

    def saveTopicCount (sc: SparkContext, topicCount: Array[Int], path: String) {
        removeAll(path+"/topicCount")
        val temp = sc.parallelize(topicCount).map {
        case (count) =>
        (count)
        }
        temp.saveAsTextFile(path+"/topicCount")
    }

    def saveLogLikelihood (sc: SparkContext,LogLikelihood:MutableList[Double], path: String) {
        removeAll(path+"/logLikelihood")
        val temp = sc.parallelize(LogLikelihood).map {
        case (count) =>
        (count)
        }
        temp.saveAsTextFile(path+"/logLikelihood")
    }

    def gibbsSampling(docTopicDistrib:Array[Int],wordTopicDistrib:Array[Int],topicCount:Array[Int],alpha:Double,beta:Double,v:Int):Int={
            val numTopic=docTopicDistrib.length
            var ro:Array[Double]=new Array[Double](numTopic)
            ro(0)=(docTopicDistrib(0)+alpha)*(wordTopicDistrib(0)+beta)/(topicCount(0)+v*beta)
            for(i<-1 to numTopic-1){
                ro(i)=ro(i-1)+(docTopicDistrib(i)+alpha)*(wordTopicDistrib(i)+beta)/(topicCount(i)+v*beta)
            }
            var x=Math.random()*ro(numTopic-1)
            var i:Int=0
            while(x>ro(i)&&i<numTopic-1)i+=1
            return i
    }

    def logLikelihood(dictionary: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Array[Int]],topicCount:Array[Int],alpha:Double,beta:Double):Double={
            val V:Int=dictionary.size
        val numTopics:Int=topicCount.length-1
        var logLikelihood:Double=numTopics*(Gamma.logGamma(V*beta)-V*Gamma.logGamma(beta))
        for (i<-0 to numTopics){
              var sum:Double=0
            dictionary.foreach{t=> sum+=Gamma.logGamma(t._2(i)+beta)
    }
    logLikelihood+=sum-Gamma.logGamma(topicCount(i)+V*beta)
    }
    (logLikelihood)
    }

    def removeAll(pathDir: String) = {
        def delete(file: File): Array[(String, Boolean)] = {
                Option(file.listFiles).map(_.flatMap(f => delete(f))).getOrElse(Array()) :+ (file.getPath -> file.delete)
        }
    }

}
```

and it has one Scala class :

```
package LDAv1

class Vector(val vect:Array[Int]) {
    var data:Array[Int]=vect;
  def this(size:Int){
    this(new Array[Int](size));
  }

  def increment(index:Int){
    data(index)+=1;
  }
  def decrement(index:Int){
    data(index)-=1;
  }
  def printIt(){
    print("[")
    for(i<-0 to data.length-1)print(data(i)+",");
        print("]\n")
  }
  def forEach(callback:(Int) => Unit)={
    for(i<-0 to data.length-1)callback(data(i));
  }
  def add(a:Array[Int]){
    for(i<-0 to data.length-1)data(i)+=a(i);
  }
  def sumAll():Int={
    var sum:Int=0;
    for(i<-0 to data.length-1)sum+=data(i);
    (sum)
  }
  def normalize():Array[Double]={
    var temp:Array[Double] = new Array[Double](data.length);

    var sum:Double=0;
    for(i<-0 to data.length-1)sum+=data(i);
      if (sum>0) {
        for(i<-0 to data.length-1) {
          temp(i) = data(i).toDouble/sum
        };
      }
    (temp) 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Build you application and use spark-submit https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html.

Comment: i've received this error when using my jar file in Spark , ERROR SparkContext: Jar not found at target/scala-2.11/jstn-1.0.jar

Comment: You should change you scala version to 2.10.4. To use version 2.11. you need to recomplie project by urself. I would recommend using sbt or maven to build to create project not separate jars.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a fat jar, with all dependencies included, then you can build your application using the spark build-in function, spark-submit.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: How can i create a jar file with all dependencies?

Comment: There are sbt plugins especially for that. E.g. the assembly plugin.